# Firebase Listener Not Working On Android Device (Sometimes)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase listeners work perfectly on iOS (**device and simulator**) and the **Android simulator**.

When connected to a **real android device**, listeners **sometimes** do not fire.

How can I go about debugging this?

When firebase listeners aren't working, the firebase auth() function is however working. So, I can authenticate a user, but I cannot retrieve data with a **.on listener**.

For example,

```
firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
.then(() => {
    console.log('this prints every time');
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snapshot) => {
            console.log('This never prints')
        });
    }
}
```

The **.on listener doesn't fire**, but the **authentication works**.

This only happens sometimes and usually waiting several hours and trying again makes it go away. Then it'll come back again.

**EDIT: After a little over an hour of waiting with the app open, the firebase listeners actually worked. But, it took more than an hour. Still have no idea why...**

**EDIT: Found these logs inside logcat in Android Studio. This same set of messages are repeated over and over again.**

**EDIT: When connecting to the internet using a mobile hotspot, the issue does NOT occur...**

```
09-23 22:25:47.920 21028-21146/com.starco.starmsg D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
09-23 22:25:47.923 21028-21146/com.starco.starmsg D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
09-23 22:25:47.924 21028-21146/com.starco.starmsg D/Connection: conn_5 - Opening a connection
09-23 22:25:49.163 21028-21372/com.starco.starmsg V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
09-23 22:26:17.925 21028-21146/com.starco.starmsg D/WebSocket: ws_5 - timed out on connect
    ws_5 - closed
    ws_5 - closing itself
09-23 22:26:17.925 21028-21146/com.starco.starmsg D/Connection: conn_5 - Realtime connection failed
    conn_5 - closing realtime connection
09-23 22:26:17.925 21028-21146/com.starco.starmsg D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
09-23 22:26:17.926 21028-21146/com.starco.starmsg D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
09-23 22:26:17.926 21028-21146/com.starco.starmsg D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 2547ms
09-23 22:26:18.991 21028-21146/com.starco.starmsg D/WebSocket: ws_5 - WebSocket error.
    bfz: error while creating secure socket to wss://star-msg.firebaseio.com/.ws?ns=star-msg&v=5
        at bfw.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@13280045@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):86)
        at bfx.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@13280045@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.connect(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:265)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.connect(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:252)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:427)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:210)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.<init>(SSLSocket.java:906)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:192)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:68)
        at bfw.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@13280045@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):70)
        at bfx.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@13280045@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Is authentication required by security rules in order to access the database in the way that you're showing?

Comment: Yes, authentication is required. But, in my actual code, I wrap the firebase listener with firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { //.on listener here }. I've also added some additional details to my post.

Comment: The only difference I can think of is that the Auth data goes over a regular HTTPS request, while the traffic of the Realtime Database goes over a (web) socket. Are you behind a firewall or proxy that might be influencing traffic? It might be worth [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)), and checking the logcat for output that hints at the cause of connection problems.

Comment: I updated my post with output from logcat. This is running on an brand new Alcatel CameoX w/ Android 7.0 device. Also, when I switch to a mobile hotspot wifi, the problem goes away. Which suggests an issue with my internet, but on iOS device, this issue doesn't occur. Clearly something with Android.

Comment: I see you get a timeout. Increase the timout value or try to make logic for retrying if a timeout occur.

Comment: How can I increase the timeout?